# Dynamic cell reference in another worksheet by referencing string in another cell as column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

Looking for a way to formulate a very typical =([worksheet]![column][row]) type formula where only the [column] is dynamic. And by dynamic I am thinking of reading the string of another cell:

- For instance let say, in worksheet_1 cell A1 contains the letter "B"
- How should I construct a my formula that would have a cell to return the value of =([worksheet that is not "worksheet_1"!B[row]), where the [column] section is referencing the cell A1 (sort of reading the string "B" and getting it as the column)

I am currently working on some financial modeling where I am extracting the numbers from a sheet with only annual numbers/ outlay to a sheet where it is shown in (quarter+annual) in consecutive column. So obviously my idea is to work around the simple "dragging" the formula, **give the outlay is not align** (where one is annual-annual-annual ... and the other is quarter-quarter-quarter-quarter-annual...).

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Use INDIRECT......

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDIRECT("worksheet_1!"&A1&ROW)
```

OR

```
=INDIRECT("worksheet_1!R"&ROW&"C"&A1,)
```